# Adding CORS module to a single express route not working

Tags: node.js, express, cors

If I [enable CORS for all routes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#simple-usage-enable-all-cors-requests), the request from the frontend (`https://localhost:3000`) works and gets the correct request headers.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.post('/api/submitEmail', () => console.log('yay'));
```

If I [enable CORS on the individual route](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enable-cors-for-a-single-route), exactly as the docs layout, I get the CORS error in the console

```
app.post('/api/submitEmail', cors(), () => console.log('booooo'));
```

Error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/submitEmail' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

What am I missing?

The entire request from the frontend below

```
const api =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
    ? "http://localhost:8000"
    : MY_PROD_URL;

const user = {
    email
  };

  axios.post(`${api}/api/submitEmail`, { user }).then(res => {
    setIsLoading(false);
    setValidationMessage(res.data);
  });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and @jfriend00 answer helped me.
You just need to include the initial options for the express app:

```
app.options('/this_is_your_cors_route', cors())
```

And then your cors route will work:

```
app.post('/this_is_your_cors_route', cors(), (req, res) => {});
```

Here are the docs for this issue: https://github.com/expressjs/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight

Answer (score 1):

You don't show us the details of the actual request, but if the request contains certain special conditions, then the browser will attempt to preflight the request with an OPTIONS request before it issues the POST.  When you insert the `cors()` call only in the `app.post()` route handler, then the OPTIONS request is not handled and if this particular cross origin request is the type that triggers an OPTIONS pre-flight, then because you don't handle it, the request will fail.

You can address that by adding this:

```
app.options('/api/submitEmail', cors(), (req, res) => res.send());
```

As this will handle the OPTIONS pre-flight for that specific route.

You can read about what a "simple request" is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests).  Anything other than a simple request requires the OPTIONS pre-flight.  It can be as simple as setting a single custom header or a content-type that isn't allowed in the simple request and that will trigger the OPTIONS pre-flight.

When you did `app.use(cors());`, that handled the pre-flight OPTIONS request for you automatically since all HTTP verbs get sent to `app.use()` handlers and the `cors()` middleware handler supports doing the right thing for an OPTIONS request.

Also, in your POST request handler, you NEED to send a response or the client will just sit there waiting for a response and eventually time out.

Comment: I added the entire route to the original question, doesn't look like it should require an OPTIONS request.

Comment: @user3521314 - It's the sender that determines whether it requires an OPTIONS request or not.  Show the sending code.

Comment: whoops, replaced with the request from the frontend.

Comment: @user3521314 - The sending code doesn't show anything that would trigger an OPTIONS request (though there could be axios defaults set elsewhere that cause it), but the only way to know for sure is to examine the actual request in the network tab in the Chrome debugger and see what the browser is actually sending.  That will also show you whether it is first doing an OPTIONS pre-flight or not and will show you what headers the browser is receiving back from the server and whether that's everything you expect to be in place or not.

Comment: @user3521314 = Hmm, I see in your detailed error message that is IS doing a pre-flight request and it is not getting the right headers on the response to the pre-flight request.  Did you try my `app.options()` suggestion?